# Replace value in data.frame with value in next column

Tags: r, rscript

I have dataframe with two columns:

```
   names duration
1      J       97
2      G       NA
3      H       53
4      A       23
5      E       NA
6      D       NA
7      C       73
8      F       NA
9      B       37
10     I       67
```

What I want to do is replace all NA values in duration column with value from names column from the same row. How can I achive that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data

```
zz <- "names duration
1      J       97
2      G       NA
3      H       53
4      A       23
5      E       NA
6      D       NA
7      C       73
8      F       NA
9      B       37
10     I       67"

df <- read.table(text = zz, header = TRUE)
```

Solution with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df_new <- df %>% 
    mutate(duration = ifelse(is.na(duration), as.character(names), duration))
```

Output

```
    df_new
    #    names duration
    # 1      J       97
    # 2      G        G
    # 3      H       53
    # 4      A       23
    # 5      E        E
    # 6      D        D
    # 7      C       73
    # 8      F        F
    # 9      B       37
    # 10     I       67
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me perfectly. I only needed to add one line of code to replace all dots with commas in duration column for numbers.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `is.na` to create a logical index and then subset both the 'names' based on the 'i1' to replace the 'duration' on the same row.

```
i1 <- is.na(df$duration)
df$duration[i1] <- df$names[i1]
df
#   names duration
#1      J       97
#2      G        G
#3      H       53
#4      A       23
#5      E        E
#6      D        D
#7      C       73
#8      F        F
#9      B       37
#10     I       67
```

NOTE: This should change the `class` of the 'duration' to `character` from `numeric`

---

Or this can be done with a faster approach with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), change the `class` of 'duration' to `character`, then by specifying the condition in 'i'  (`is.na(duration)`), we assign  (`:=`) the values in 'name' that correspond to the 'i' condition to 'duration'.  As the assignment happens in place, it will be very efficient.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, duration:= as.character(duration)][is.na(duration), duration:= names]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(names = c("J", "G", "H", "A", "E", "D", "C", "F", 
"B", "I"), duration = c(97L, NA, 53L, 23L, NA, NA, 73L, NA, 37L, 
67L)), .Names = c("names", "duration"), row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```